# ADFS relying party token encryption certificate .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs

We have a .net MVC web application where authentication has to be done from ADFS. ADFS setup sits in client network/server and our application will be deployed in cloud environment.
we have successfully added Relying party with WS-Federation passive protocol and also able to authenticate and get the claims in our application. But while configuring RP, we have not used any token encryption certificate. so, now want to know what is this token signing certificate is all about. Can we send our website SSL certificate only to add as token signing certificate or anything else we need to do here?
your responses are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS only issues tokens via HTTPS so the token is protected by the channel. However, it is optionally possible to encrypt the token specifically to the RP, so that only the RP can view info. This ensures that the client can never see the contents of the token. Always note that integrity is maintained through the signature and cannot be tampered by the client.

So, unless you are issuing sensitive data that should never ever be seen by prying eyes, you don't need to encrypt the token.

//Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: Thanks Sam for the reply. I want to know on what certificate we can use when "configure certificate" when adding RP. I have my website SSL certificate. Can i send the same certificate to the ADFS team to add in that step? If so, then when i get the token back, does IIS automatically decrypt the token using the certificate?